# SCD-2 Using Delta in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to build the SCD-2 transformation, but not able to implement using Delta in Databricks.

Example:

```
//Base Table
 val employeeDf = Seq((1,"John","CT"),
                     (2,"Mathew","MA"),
                     (3,"Peter","CA"),
                     (4,"Joel","NY"))
                    .toDF("ID","NAME","ADDRESS")

val empBaseDf = employeeDf.withColumn("IS_ACTIVE",lit(1))
  .withColumn("EFFECTIVE_DATE",current_date())
  .withColumn("TERMINATION_DATE",lit(null).cast(StringType))      

empBaseDf.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("empBase")
```

---

```
// Batch Data
//Note: Here 1 record changed, 2 new record and 1 unchnaged.
val updateEmployeeDf = Seq( (1,"John","NH"),
                 (2,"Mathew","MA"),
                (5,"Adam","NJ"),
                (6,"Philip","CT")).toDF("ID","NAME","ADDRESS").createOrReplaceTempView("EmpUpdates")


val updatedEmp = updateEmployeeDf.withColumn("IS_ACTIVE",lit(1))
      .withColumn("EFFECTIVE_DATE",current_date())
      .withColumn("TERMINATION_DATE",lit(null).cast(StringType))      

updatedEmp.createOrReplaceTempView("empBatch")
```

---

```
import io.delta.tables._    
val empbaseTable: DeltaTable =  DeltaTable.forName("empBase")          
val empBatch = table("empBatch")

// Rows to INSERT new addresses of existing customers
val newAddressesToInsert = empBatch
  .as("batch")
  .join(empbaseTable.toDF.as("emp"), "ID")
  .where("batch.ADDRESS <> emp.ADDRESS").selectExpr("batch.*")

newAddressesToInsert.show()
```

---

```
val processRec = newAddressesToInsert
  .selectExpr("NULL as mergeKey", "*")
  .union(empBatch.selectExpr("ID as mergeKey", "*")  )                 
processRec.show()
```

---

```
empbaseTable
  .as("base")
  .merge(processRec.as("batch1"),"base.ID = mergeKey")
  .whenMatched("base.IS_ACTIVE = true AND base.address <> batch1.address")
  .updateExpr(Map(                                      
    "IS_ACTIVE" -> "false",
    "TERMINATION_DATE" -> "current_date()"))
  .whenNotMatched()  
  .insertExpr((Map("ID" -> "batch1.ID",
              "NAME" -> "batch1.NAME",
              "ADDRESS" -> "batch1.ADDRESS",             
              "IS_ACTIVE" -> "true",              
              "EFFECTIVE_DATE" -> "current_date()",
               "TERMINATION_DATE" -> "null" )))
  .execute()

//With multiple run of the above code duplicate records are getting inserted. I need to restrict the duplicate entry into the delta table.
ID  NAME    ADDRESS IS_ACTIVE   EFFECTIVE_DATE  TERMINATION_DATE
1   John    NH  1   2020-06-25  null
1   John    CT  0   2020-06-25  2020-06-25
1   John    NH  1   2020-06-25  null
2   Mathew  MA  1   2020-06-25  null
3   Peter   CA  1   2020-06-25  null
4   Joel    NY  1   2020-06-25  null
5   Adam    NJ  1   2020-06-25  null
6   Philip  CT  1   2020-06-25  null
```

I followed the documentation from databricks for SCD-2 transformation, but not working for me. https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#write-change-data-into-a-delta-table

Any suggestion is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating a new entry for the update received for the employee record, you have to ensure that the update record should be validated against the latest entry for the employee in the employee table by adding the predicate `emp.IS_ACTIVE = true`, this will avoid the duplicates.

```
// Rows to INSERT new addresses of existing customers
val newAddressesToInsert = empBatch
  .as("batch")
  .join(empbaseTable.toDF.as("emp"), "ID")
  .where("emp.IS_ACTIVE = true and batch.ADDRESS <> emp.ADDRESS").selectExpr("batch.*")
```